# android jetpack compose rememberInfiniteTransition tween durationMillis >= 90195.The animation will stay at the last stitch

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Sorry, I can hardly speak English.

android jetpack compose rememberInfiniteTransition tween durationMillis >= 90195.The animation will stay at the last stitch.

jetpack compose: v1.0.0-alpha12

machine translation:
The animation will stay at the last stitch. DurationMillis less than or equal to 90194 is animation work, but it is very stuck.

```
    /**
     * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#rememberinfinitetransition">rememberInfiniteTransition</a>
     * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#updatetransition">updateTransition</a>
     */
    val translation by rememberInfiniteTransition().animateValue(
        initialValue = 60.dp,
        targetValue = (-60).dp,
        typeConverter = Dp.VectorConverter,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(90195, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ),
    )

 

    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.welcome_page_posters),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .scale(3.8f)
            .offset(x = translation, y = (-5).dp),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. It has been fixed and you can expect to get the fix in the beta02 release. :-)